# How do I prevent network access from virtual machine to the host computer?

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, hosts

I have VirtualBox i installed a Windows 10 virtual machine and i wanted to surf the Dark web (because i worried about getting any viruses so i created a virtual machine) and to test some Malwares and other viruses.

So the remain question is:

**- How do i prevent network access from virtual machine to the host computer ?**

So do i'm right ? if i prevented network access it will not affect the host computer ? if i was fault please show me the right way

I want a clear as possible answers, and thanks !

Comment: Disconnecting your VM from the internet after you have the virus would be the best.

Comment: The default VBox connection setting (NAT) is good enough. Avoid 'Host' connection settings.

Comment: Wouldn't using "tails" be a better option here? Run it on a USB, you can even disable the hard drive in the bios when you do so.

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 so the default option NAT will not affect the Host?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 Even with viruses and Dark Web?

Comment: When it comes to viruses, you'll have to use the virtual machine *without* Virtualbox's Guest Additions.

Comment: So if it related with Dark net i don't need to change network option if it related with viruses i need to use it like what you said ?

Comment: As long as the internet connection method is `NAT` and Guest Additions is not installed, you will be fine. Just be wary of any 'Shared Folders' that you may set up.